# CvKNearest_ update Pre-existing responses

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, classification

In the CvKNearest class,How can I update Pre-existing responses or How can I delete part of Pre-existing trainData & responses?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete or edit any pre-existing features & responses in the CvKnearest.In the first append new trainData & response to CvKnearest then create a list for maintain deleted response.When use find_nearest for compute results .each results item is in the deleted list not consider in the computation.